# Excluding a long list of words with grep

Tags: bash

This Bash program extracts the 20 first lines of each `man` page present on a system and uses `grep` to remove lines matching a list of selected terms.

How can I improve the `grep` part? (something less repetitive, with less pipe but that do the same job)

```
#!/bin/bash

# generate the list
compgen -c > man

# extract each man of the list                                                                                                          
while read -r LINE; do
MANWIDHT=80 man "$LINE" | head -20 | grep -v NAME | grep -v 1 | grep -v SYNOPSIS | grep -v SYNOPSYS | grep -v OVERVIEW | grep -v VERSION | grep -v VERSION | grep -v INTRODUCTION | grep -v 5 | grep -v ABSTRACT | grep -v 4 | grep -v DESCRIPTION | grep -v COPYRIGHT | grep -v ABRT | grep -v SEE | grep -v 8 | grep -v case | grep -v 2 | grep -v STATUS | grep -v CHECK | grep -v UNIX | grep -v FORTUNE | grep -v PROLOG | grep -v Usage | grep -v Help | grep -v Introduction | grep -v Local | grep -v ARGUMENTS | grep -v SYNTAX | grep -v NOTE | grep -v QUERYING | grep -v 3 | grep -v Description | grep -v Note | grep -v Name | grep -v COPYING | grep -v COMMAND | grep -v USAGE | grep -v EXAMPLE | grep -v 3 | grep -v OPTIONS | grep -v AUTHOR | grep -v DOCUMENTS | grep -v SUMMARY | grep -v -e '^$' && echo -en '\n'
done < man > man1

# add the % to each empty line                                                                                                          
sed -i -e 's/^$/%/' man1

# merge to fortune-rtfm db                                                                                                              
cat man1 > fortune-rtfm
```

Comment: You can test it on your computer and/or if you already have an Archlinux you can test it directly with the package https://github.com/aurelien-git/fortune-mod-rtfm

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, avoid excessively long lines that force reviewers to scroll horizontally far far right. You can break lines to manageable length like this:

```
MANWIDHT=80 man "$LINE" | head -20 | grep -v NAME | grep -v 1 | \
grep -v SYNOPSIS | grep -v SYNOPSYS | grep -v OVERVIEW | grep -v VERSION | \
grep -v VERSION | grep -v INTRODUCTION | grep -v 5 | grep -v ABSTRACT | \
...
```

You are using too many temporary files. You could chain the commands together in a single pipeline, without unnecessary temporary files:

```
compgen -c | while read -r LINE; do
    MANWIDHT=80 man "$LINE" | head -20 | grep -v NAME | ...
done | sed -e 's/^$/%/' > fortune-rtfm
```

Instead of a chain of `grep -v word1 | grep -v word2 | grep -v word3`,
you can use a single `grep` with multiple `-e` parameters like this:

```
grep -v -e word1 -e word2 -e word3
```

A single `grep` process instead of dozens will certainly run much faster.

A simple `echo` is the same as `echo -en '\n'`, but better in every way.

Finally, instead of a long `grep` with all the terms you want to exclude, you can put them in a file, one word per line, and use the `-f` flag of `grep` to use that list. Then the script can be shortened to:

```
#!/bin/bash

compgen -c | while read -r LINE; do
    MANWIDHT=80 man "$LINE" | head -20 | grep -v -f words.txt | grep -v '^$' && echo
done | sed -e 's/^$/%/' > fortune-rtfm
```

@Sundeep pointed out a few important things in a comment. `MANWIDHT` is misspelled, it should be `MANWIDTH`.
Also, since the patterns are fixed strings (as opposed to regular expressions), it's good to add the `-F` flag so that `grep` can optimize the matching. Lastly, you might want to match whole words instead of parts of words. If that's the case, add the `-w` flag. This is equivalent to wrapping each pattern within `\<...\>`. (The effect is that for example "VERSIONING" is matched by `grep VERSION`, but by `grep -w VERSION`.)

The content of `words.txt`, sorted for easier reading, is something like this (just the first bunch of lines):

```
1
2
3
4
5
8
ABRT
ABSTRACT
ARGUMENTS
AUTHOR
CHECK
COMMAND
COPYING
... (and so on)
```

If you want to keep all the patterns inside your script file, you can do that too, for example like this:

```
compgen -c | while read -r LINE; do
    MANWIDHT=80 man "$LINE" | head -20 | grep -vFf <(cat << EOF
1 2 3 3 4 5 8 
ABRT ABSTRACT ARGUMENTS AUTHOR 
CHECK COMMAND COPYING COPYRIGHT 
DESCRIPTION DOCUMENTS Description 
EXAMPLE 
FORTUNE 
Help 
INTRODUCTION Introduction 
Local 
NAME NOTE Name Note 
OPTIONS OVERVIEW 
PROLOG 
QUERYING 
SEE STATUS SUMMARY SYNOPSIS SYNOPSYS SYNTAX 
UNIX USAGE Usage 
VERSION 
case 
EOF
) | grep -v '^$' && echo
done | sed -e 's/^$/%/' > fortune-rtfm
```

Comment: Well that sounds fine at first, but, your code does not works as is. The code I have write works. Their is certainly not a lot to change ... but i do not get it for the moment.

Comment: @aurelien I ran both scripts, yours and mine, and they give identical output.

Comment: Yes thanks I  am running it ... sounds perfect ... I have now to understand ... how you find that great way!

Answer (score 3):

This is a little more palatable:

```
excluded_words=(
    1 2 3 3 4 5 8 
    ABRT ABSTRACT ARGUMENTS AUTHOR 
    CHECK COMMAND COPYING COPYRIGHT 
    DESCRIPTION DOCUMENTS Description 
    EXAMPLE 
    FORTUNE 
    Help 
    INTRODUCTION Introduction 
    Local 
    NAME NOTE Name Note 
    OPTIONS OVERVIEW 
    PROLOG 
    QUERYING 
    SEE STATUS SUMMARY SYNOPSIS SYNOPSYS SYNTAX 
    UNIX USAGE Usage 
    VERSION 
    case 
)

MANWIDTH=80 man "$LINE" |
  head -20 |
  grep -vFwf <(printf "%s\n" "${excluded_words[@]}") |
  grep -v -e '^$' &&
  echo -en '\n'
```

Comment: Oh with an exclude list inside as I have tried once but do not find the way to write it correctly! Thanks @glenjackman